# Parrot Security OS Bootable USB Installation error

Tags: linux, usb, kali-linux

It's not my first time installing OS's with bootable flash drives, but with Parrot Security OS I run into a little problem. Once I choose the installation option or the graphical installation as well the display is all shrunk and kind of scrambled. But the live test option seems to work perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: Please flesh out this question a bit, beginning with a description of the hardware.

Comment: Lenovo ideapad S400, intel core i3 procesor, 4GB of RAM.
The live option works just fine, in fact im using it right now, but neither the installation option from the live or the boot seems to work. The picture above is from the boot option, it displays something but is all in the upper part of the screen, so its impossible to read. Ive read that it might be the software used to create the bootable usb, but im using ROSA which is the one recomended in the parrot website. Idk what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue today and came up with a workaround.

1. Boot from USB and enter live mode
2. Open terminal and run this command:

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/debian-installer-launcher --text
   ```
3. Win

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. I had to use their Etcher usb creator to make a usb that would install it correctly. Rufus (i've used for years) and others just wouldn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User:Thankyou for your answer. Please read How to recommend software :- [softwarerecs.se] and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- [Answer]  again welcome to superuser.Thankyou